# Output in a different format

Tags: powershell

I'm hitting an API endpoint for the UniFi Controller.

I run a command to give me devices that do NOT have a specific MAC address.

The command returns 3 mac addresses.

When working with PowerShell, how can you use the 3 mac addresses returned as 3 different items so that I can do a 'foreach' statement on them?

```
$returnedDevices = $response.data | select mac | where-object {$_.mac -notlike "18:e8:29:4f:0b:33"}
```

This is what is returned:

```
mac              
---              
80:2a:a8:c9:c3:c3
18:e8:29:93:00:d1
18:e8:29:93:6c:85
```

When I run: $returnedDevices.Count
I get '3'.

So it looks like 3 different values, but if I try to use this in a ForEach statement:

```
ForEach ($item in $returnedDevices) {

$command = "`{`"cmd`":`"restart`",`"reboot_type`":`"soft`"`,`"mac`":`"$item.mac`"`}"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$devURI" -Method Post -Body $command -ContentType "application/json" -WebSession $session
}
```

What happens is I get an error because this is what is being sent to the API:

```
{"cmd":"restart","reboot_type":"soft","mac":"@{mac=80:2a:a8:c9:c3:c3}.mac"}
```

I would think, it should be:

```
{"cmd":"restart","reboot_type":"soft","mac":"80:2a:a8:c9:c3:c3}.mac"}
```

How can I either trim the beginning or, better yet, get the right format?

Also, if I do the following, the output looks like what I would expect:

```
$item.mac
```

Output:

```
80:2a:a8:c9:c3:c3
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write a variable and its property inside of a string, that property becomes part of the quoted string.

```
$command = "`{`"cmd`":`"restart`",`"reboot_type`":`"soft`"`,`"mac`":`"$item.mac`"`}"
# vs
$command = "`{`"cmd`":`"restart`",`"reboot_type`":`"soft`"`,`"mac`":`"$($item.mac)`"`}"
```

1st Command is going to display $item but consider `.mac` to be part of the regular string. If you need to get the mac out of the variable $item and display it, you have to use the whole thing as a variable... and thats by encapsulating them with $().

Comment: Ah!  Good to know.  Thank you very much!